# How to replace/change the icon of an action bar item

Tags: android, replace, icons, action

I hope you can give me a hand on this one.

I have an Action bar item with a default icon set.(android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_volume_on")
but the thing is that i need to change it somehow programmatically at my method "onOptionsItemSelected"  and since I recently started with Android I'm a bit lost...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to save a menu instance on the `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
private Menu menu;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    this.menu = menu
    ...
}
```

Then, you can create the following method:

```
private void setItemView(int itemId, int layoutId) {
    if (menu != null) {
        final Menuitem myItem = menu.findItem(itemId);
        if (myItem != null) {
            MenuItemCompat.setActionView(myItem, layoutId);
        }
    }
}
```

It replaces the current icon of your item by a view. For example if you want to display a `ProgressBar` you can create this layout (let's name it `item_custom_view.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="56dp" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Finally, in your `Activity`, just call the `setItemView` method. Put in parameters the id of your item and the id of your layout (in this case `R.layout.item_custom_view`).

Comment: Yeah, that gaved me a workaround, thanks a lot, at the end I fixed it with:

final MenuItem myItem = menu.findItem(R.id.stop_music);
myItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_volume_muted);

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply by defining

```
private Menu menu;
```

and in onCreateOptionMenu callback assign value to menu and get menu inflater like this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.menu=menu;
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_bar, menu);
    return true;
}
```

And finally you can write this line to change icon in your preferred method

```
menu.findItem(R.id.item_id).setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon);
```